# File shows up in zipinfo but not unzip?

Tags: zip, unzip

I have a huge (~300GB) zipped archive and I'm trying to extract a few files from it while ignoring the rest. Running `zipinfo` on the archive brings up a list of files but when I try to extract one of those files using `unzip -p`, I get a "no matches found" error. I tried running `unzip -l` and in fact, some files listed by `zipinfo` just don't seem to exist on the list produced by `unzip -l`. However, when I run `unzip -v`, I do see the file that I'd like to extract.

The permissions on the file I'm trying to extract are -rw-r--r-- if that matters, but I don't think that is the cause of my problem. Is it possible to extract this hidden file?

UPDATE:
I used `unzip` to unzip the entire directory in which my target file was, and the unzipped folder did indeed contain the file which did not show up with `unzip -l`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: More info would be helpful. From the question, there are clues (e.g., permissions) you're using Linux,  but state what distro. What other applications have you tried, e.g. p7zip (or the latest Windows 7-Zip, which runs quite well under wine and is more recent than p7zip)?

Comment: You mention `zip -p` for extracting -- I assume you mean `unzip -p`. Can you provide the full command lines you have tried?